# Derivative of the product rule

Tags: derivatives

$$y=u\times v$$

How does one derive this formula, called the product rule?

$$y^{'}=uv^{'}+u^{'}v$$

Comment: Have a look at this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeProofs.aspx#Extras_DerPf_ChainRule

Comment: Surely this is the Product Rule, not the Chain Rule?

Comment: @coffeee What you have written is the product rule, not the chain rule. You can prove the product rule by using first principle ([link](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeProofs.aspx)).

Comment: @ancientmathematician my confusion exactly. I have submitted an edit.

Comment: Check this out for the product rule — http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DerivativeProofs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of the limit (for conciseness, omitting $\lim_{h\to0}$ and computing at $x=0$ WLOG),

$$\frac{u(h)v(h)-u(0)v(0)}{h}=\frac{u(h)v(h)\color{green}{-u(h)v(0)+u(h)v(0)}-u(0)v(0)}{h}
\\=u(h)\frac{v(h)-v(0)}{h}+\frac{u(h)-u(0)}{h}v(0).$$

The claim follows from the computation rules on limits, and from the continuity of $u$ that ensures $\lim_{h\to0}u(h)=u(0)$.